# Can I access different business lounges?

Tags: lufthansa, lounges, muc

In a few days I'll have a trip with Lufthansa with a 12-hour connection in Munich. My idea is that after landing I go have a breakfast to the business lounge in the Schengen area, and after this I go to the city. In the evening I go through passport control and then have dinner in the non-Schengen Lufthansa lounge.

Can I visit these two lounges during the day? Or maybe after visiting the first one my pass is used up and they will not allow me to enter the second one. Does somebody have such experience with Lufthansa?

Comment: Don’t know the layout in Munich, but in most European airports the arrivals area is separated from the departures area, so unless there’s a dedicated arrivals lounge, you usually can’t get to a lounge when arriving, unless you enter the secure area (transit / connection) for your departing flight, and you usually cannot leave that area (or at least not easily), so you would be stuck in the airport until your next flight...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on your status and ticket type(s). Access rules are fairly complicated: See https://www.lufthansa.com/us/en/Lounge-types-and-access

In "most" cases (business class ticket and/or Star Alliance Gold), you will need a same day **departure** boarding pass to access the lounge. So if you already have a boarding pass for your connecting flight when you arrive, or if you can check in right away, you can access the lounge (provided you have proper access credentials in the first place).

You can enter and leave any qualifying lounge in the airport as often as you like. "Lounge hopping" can be fun, if you have a long layover and are stuck at the airport.